# Android service error “Unfortunately Service has stopped” but code has no errors LogCat error = FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service, logcat, runtimeexception

I am trying to get this `Service` to open another app upon start up using the URI in the code. My `BroadcastReciever` and manifest have the correct code so I suspect it is something in this `mainActivity`.

I am using Eclipse and there are no errors or warning but when run on the phone i get the following error:

> Unfortunately anyConnectService has stopped

The LogCat has the following as the first error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anyconnect/com.anyconnectservice,MainActivity}
```

Please glance at the following code and offer a solution.

Thanks

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends Service
{
    @override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, “Service created”,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri anyConnectUri = Uri.parse(“anyconnect://connect/name= TestVPN”);
        Intent arg0 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, anyConnectUri);
        this.startActivity(arg0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have to set component:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an Activity that can `VIEW` the content of data you put in the Intent.

But if you do not have any installed applications that listens for a message of type: `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, and accepts a Uri, then most probably the application will throw an exception.

From your description: `service to open **another app**`.
Well, it seems that "another app" can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be (no `abstract`):

```
public class MainActivity extends Service
{
    @override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, “Service created”,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri anyConnectUri = Uri.parse(“anyconnect://connect/name= TestVPN”);
        Intent arg0 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, anyConnectUri);
        this.startActivity(arg0);
    }
}
```

Though you might want to change the name of the class to better reflect its use, as this is as services and not an activity.